# Android app with size = null in Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I have a react-native app released for Android, available on Play Store. The apk size is approximately 9mb but when users install it form the store they are required to have 260mb available.

When I check the size of the app at the store I see a "null" under the "Size" field. Please see image below:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a bug in the Play Store and I have reported it.

I suspect what has happened is you have more than one active version of the Play store your devices are eligible for - maybe one is eligible for an alpha or beta version (do you see how current version says "varies with device").

Because you have more than one different current version, a size cannot be displayed.

Comment: Can you share a link for the reported issue?

Comment: No, I have reported it internally at Google.

Comment: Ok. Just to let you know, after I removed the only retained APK that I had the issue went away, so it seems that you were right.

On the other hand let me ask you a question, maybe you know the answer. My app is now "properly sized" by Play Store, it correctly says 8.53mb. My cellphone is a little "short" on psychical space and when I try to install the Play Store requires me to have 270mb of free space available. Why could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Augusto, I have a similar problem too.

My app is published correctly, no error is reported, but the value of the size in Play Store is null (before it was 0) and the application is not downloadable.

I reported my problem to the support but after more than 2 weeks I did not have a solution yet.
I saw that you ask for the link for the reported issue, here it is:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs?hl=en

Comment: In my case the app is downloadable but it requires the user to have like 260mb of storage space available when the app actually takes around of 25mb. I have an old retained APK, I will try getting rid of it and see if that was causing the issue. I will let you know.